# How to get the data that is not loaded in the target table?

Tags: etl, sap-data-services

I am having a small ETL mapping in SAP BODS where the Source table data is loaded into the target table. But there are chances where some rows might be having some errors and may be skipped.

I want to store the count of all these rows that are skipped by BODS into another table(C).

Can someone please help me with this?

[image: inside SAP DATA SERVICE DESGNER>job>workflow>DataFlow]

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch elements of BODS and wrap your data flow in it

[image]

The function `error_context()` is available in catch block which allows fetching the cause of error. With the help of custom function you can write these details into other table.

For capturing erroneous rows use **Overflow file** setting in target table

[image]

All skipped rows will be written into that file. More detailed [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/04/error-handling-and-recovery-mechanisms-is-sap-data-services-42/).

P.S. All images are copyrighted by SAP (C)